# JSOUP: Allow only image tags

Tags: jsoup

I would like a help in JSOUP to allow only image tags.

My string look like this:

```
<p>some text here</p>
<p>some text here</p> 
<p><img alt="alt" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" /></p>
<p><img alt="alt" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" /></p> 
<p>some text here</p>
```

using this code in JSOUP i manage to get the following:

```
Whitelist customwhitelist1 = new Whitelist();
customwhitelist1.addAttributes("img", "src", "alt");
String final = Jsoup.clean(unsafe, customwhitelist1);

some text heresome text here
<img alt="alt" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
<img alt="alt" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
some text here
```

but my final output should be

```
<img alt="alt" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
<img alt="alt" src="http://www.example.com/image.jpg" />
```

any suggestions? thanks

Comment: Do you want to select the `<img>` tags and write it out?

Answer (score 1):

If you just need the img tags in the document, you need not use whitelist. Instead you could do like

```
doc.html(doc.select("img").toString());
```

Also if you want the document body to contain only img tags then do like

```
doc.body().html(doc.select("img").toString());
```

Answer (score 0):

When you clean using JSoup it doesn't remove the `InnerText` value, so to get the result you want you will have to remove the `<p>` tags before you run a clean.

First you'll have to remove the `<p>` tags with the text, and since there is no child nodes in them you can remove them by selecting out of that.

```
//Select all the p-tags, if they have a zero size list of children, remove them
Document doc =  Jsoup.parse(html);
for (Element e : doc.select("p")) {
    if(e.children().size() == 0){
        e.remove();
    }
}
```

After that, clean your document!

```
String final = Jsoup.clean(doc.body().html(), customwhitelist1);
```

Comment: your code removes the images as well because they are included into <p> tags as well.

Comment: True! I'll have to look at it a bit further!